How did A.A.R.O. fabricate this character's human history?
This question is full of spoilers. Read at your own risk.
.
.
.
.
.

Toward the end of season 1 of A.A.R.O. - All-Domain Anomaly Resolution Office, it is revealed that protagonist Koyume Amano is a goddess who lost her memories while hunting for Hiruko.
The basic perspective for her was to live out her life as an ordinary human, but due to a faint glimmer of hope of restoring her memories as a goddess, the others let her work at A.A.R.O.
So, before her memories were erased by means of the "separation ritual", she had actually been working as the head of A.A.R.O. and she had been fully aware of being a goddess. After the separation ritual, she had been reintegrated into A.A.R.O. as an ordinary human, with the false identity of a police officer working in the PR department.
But how could this false identity have worked out?

The false identity as a police officer may work for Koyume to make sense of her personal history herself, and to the outside world to explain where the new A.A.R.O. employee comes from. But we see that Mr. Ukino asks Mr. Naobi on their first encounter to reassign (now human) Koyume from the police to A.A.R.O. - so was Koyume actually assigned to some police office before?
After the others have made her forget, Koyume wakes up in her apartment. She is a bit confused about what has happened before. Next, she is seen talking to a group of (human) women who appear to be her good friends - but how could they know her? Were they hired to pretend being Koyume's long-term friends, possibly indefinitely if she does not regain her memories?

